# how do we create server side templates with django

Tags: python-3.x, django, server

let's take the example of Fiverr to explain what is basically my question. When an offer is generated on Fiverr, they say today is 5% off and a pop/modal is seen. you press cross it closes. what I want to know is this an example of server-side templates?

and how to get started with server-side templates with Django

Answer (score 0):

For the example given in the question, it **is not** a server-side function that closes the pop-up it is client-side (javascript and css) that closes the pop-up.

A server-side template is what generates the page and send its to the client when the url is requested, in most cases the server-side template is is only refreshed when the client refreshes the page or requests a new page.

You can [read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/) about Django's tempting system which is a server-side tempting engine, by following along with the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/) in the documentation.